# How to adjust hanging width in titlesec?

Tags: titlesec

I want to achieve a section/subsection arrangement that looks like the one below:
[image]

Where the subsection is indented and the multiline title is completely set apart as its own block of text. You can use the `[hang]` option with `titlesec`to achieve this look for the unindented section title, but the after using the following code: `\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\hspace{2em}\normalfont\itshape\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{1em}{}` you get this:

[image]

Because the hang width is now not wide enough to push the title past "A." Thus, is there anyway to adjust the hang for various different levels of title.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.